# I am unable to read the data after aggregation one by one...in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I did an aggregation query for match and tried to print the value of _id... but was undefined... how to unwind there from an array
below shown is my code

```js
    Student.aggregate([
        {    $match: { 'name': studentName} }
      ]).then(function (res) {
        for(var i in res){
          console.log(res._id)
        }
        console.log(res)
      })
```

Comment: what is `res` displaying?

Comment: I want only _id,, I just checked if data coming in res

Comment: then write `console.log(i._id)`

Comment: and please use `for(var i of res)`

Comment: yeah got...thankyou @Ifaruki